# Updating Mongoose schema with JSON object via REST endpoint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, rest

I have a REST endpoint that is being submitted with a JSON object (User) and I just set the corresponding mongo record to that JSON object. This saves me the trouble of updating schema changes in the service method and the endpoint leaving just the Mongoose model to update.

What would be a more secure way of doing this, if any?

**Example User JSON**

```
{
  'fname': 'Bill',
  'lname': 'Williams',
  'email': 'bill@billwilliams.com',
  'settings': {
    'strokeColor': '#FF0000'
  }
}
```

**From my Angular service**

```
Update: function(my_user) {
  return $http.put('http://api.domain.com/v1/api/users/' + _user.id, {
    user: my_user,
    token: window.localStorage['token']
  });
}
```

**My REST endpoint in Node**

```
api.route('/users/:user_id')
  .put(function(req, res) {

    User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user) {
      userData = req.body.user;

      if (user) {
        //-- This is potential trouble area?
        User.update({'_id': user._id}, {$set: userData});

      user.save(function(err) {
          res.json({
            success: true,
            message: 'User updated'
          });
  }); //-- end findById()
}); //-- end /users/:user_id put() route
```

Comment: You should definitely validate that object to ensure it only has the keys that the specific user is allowed to update/add, and that the user is allowed to update that specific user record.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken).

It basically works like this:

1. Create a REST endpoint that lets users aquire a token with a certain
   payload (id for example)
2. Secure the relevant part of your api with the Jsonwebtoken middleware (if using express as the webserver)
3. User adds the token to every request header (by using $httpInterceptor)
4. Token is checked on the server side **before** the request reaches your API

Tokens may expire after a certain time (useful when users needs to register first) which adds additional security.

Comment: I am currently using JWT, I'm more worried about if a person does get authenticated and somehow manipulates their own JSON and POSTs it.

Comment: OK, I'm curious how others may answer that question. BTW: Why do you update AND save the user. One of both should be sufficient.